# Awesome Window Manager - Rule assigning programs to tags

Tags: rules, awesome-wm, lua

I have a set of tags 'main', 'www', and 3:

```
-- {{{ Tags
tags = {
    names = {"main", "www", 3},
    for s = 1, screen.count() do
       tags[s] = awful.tag(tags.names, s, tags.layout)
    end
}
-- }}}
```

I want Firefox to open in tag "www". I've tried the following rule:

```
-- {{{ Rules
awful.rules.rules = {
    { rule = {class = "Firefox" },
      properties = { tag = tags[1]["www"] }},
}
-- }}}
```

However, if I hit Super+R then type 'firefox' or run 'firefox &' from a terminal, Firefox opens in whatever tag I'm viewing.

I've tried `{class = "firefox"}` and `properties = { tag = tags[1][2] }` but those modified rules did not work either.

What is the correct way to set up a rule to make firefox always open in a particular tag?

Comment: Did you restart awesome to make sure the config changes are applied ? If yes, then I suspect something like "the rules are applied when the client first exists, but it doesn't have this class yet". You can check that the rules are applied when you *restart* awesome (with the firefox window open on the wrong tag, it should move to the right one). If so, it's not a match problem, and you should seek to `awful.rules.apply()` to your firefox client at some point after it's creation. If the rule is not applied, then there's a problem with the matcher. See http://superuser.com/q/513707/162290

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just going to paste my excerpts here. These are confirmed working as of 3.4.10+.

```
...
 62 -- {{{ Tags
 63 -- Define a tag table which will hold all screen tags.
 64 tags = {                                                                                                                                                                                      
 65     names  = { "1www", "2 @ ", "3trm", "4off", "5msg", "6vmr", 7, "8tom", "9log" },
 66     layout = { layouts[1], layouts[2], layouts[3], layouts[2], layouts[3],
 67                layouts[3], layouts[3], layouts[3], layouts[3] }
 68 }
 69 for s = 1, screen.count() do
 70     -- Each screen has its own tag table.
 71     tags[s] = awful.tag(tags.names, s, tags.layout)
 72 end
 73 -- }}}
...
408 -- {{{ Rules
409 awful.rules.rules = {
410     -- All clients will match this rule.
411     { rule = { },
412       properties = { border_width = beautiful.border_width,
413                      border_color = beautiful.border_normal,
414                      focus = true,
415                      keys = clientkeys,
416                      buttons = clientbuttons } },
417     -- Set Firefox to always map on tags number 1 of screen 1.
418     { rule = { class = "Firefox" },
419        properties = { tag = tags[1][1] } },
420     { rule = { class = "Gvim" },
421       properties = { size_hints_honor = false } },
422     { rule = { class = "KeePass.exe" },
423        properties = { maximized_vertical = true, maximized_horizontal = true } },
424     { rule = { class = "Mirage" },
425        properties = { maximized_vertical = true, maximized_horizontal = true } },
426     { rule = { class = "Navigator" },
427        properties = { tag = tags[1][1], maximized_vertical = true, maximized_horizontal = true } },
428     { rule = { class = "pinentry" },
429       properties = { floating = true } },
430     { rule = { class = "Skype" },
431       properties = { tag = tags[1][5] } },
432     { rule = { class = "Thunderbird" },
433        properties = { tag = tags[1][2] } },
434     { rule = { class = "Tomboy" },
435        properties = { tag = tags[1][8] } },
436     { rule = { class = "URxvt" },
437       properties = { size_hints_honor = false } },
438     { rule = { class = "Vncviewer" },
439        properties = { maximized_vertical = true, maximized_horizontal = true } },
440     { rule = { class = "XMind" },
441        properties = { maximized_vertical = true, maximized_horizontal = true } },
442     { rule = { class = "XTerm" },
443       properties = { size_hints_honor = false } },
444     { rule = { instance = "XTerm-logs" },
445        properties = { tag = tags[1][9] } },
446 }
447 -- }}}
```

I have no idea how Lua deals with whitespace, I do notice your curly braces and whitespaces are inconsistent.

Comment: Lua is almost as agnostic as C to whitespace. If brackets match, it's happy.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit speculative but I suggest retrying what you say you did:  `{class = "firefox"}` and `properties = { tag = tags[1][2] }`  but *capitalize* the first letter of `firefox`.  It matters.

Answer (score 0):

tag array is indexed by numerals.

```
properties = { tag = tags[1]["www"] }},
```

So should be:

```
properties = { tag = tags[1][2] }},
```

Comment: And that's probably not the only problem, but on my setup, this is correct.