# Always open applications in associated workspace in awesome window manager

Tags: boot, window-manager, awesome-wm, application-launch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [awesome-wm: binding programs to workspaces](https://superuser.com/questions/344227/awesome-wm-binding-programs-to-workspaces)

Is it possible to open a particular application always in an associated workspace in awesome window manager? For e.g. I want to open the browser always in the "web" workspace i have.

If awesome window manager cannot do, is there any other tiling window manager can do the same?

Comment: Duplicate of at least http://superuser.com/questions/315770/awesome-window-manager-rule-assigning-programs-to-tags, http://superuser.com/questions/344227/awesome-wm-binding-programs-to-workspaces

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in your `rc.lua` files with a custom rule.

I have something like this:

```
-- {{{ Rules
awful.rules.rules = {
    // ...
    { rule = { class = "Chrome" },
      properties = { tag = tags[1][2] } },
    { rule = { class = "Qmpdclient" },
      properties = { tag = tags[1][9] } },
    // ...
}
```

which makes Chrome always start on the second workspace of the first screen, and Qmpdclient on the ninth.

Comment: Hello Sundar, I hope it works for you (be careful with the syntax!). Generally, you should not mark an answer as accepted (the green checkmark) until you've verified it works for you. If you realize it does not do what you want, remember to remove the checkmark - otherwise, less people will look at your question, so you are less likely to get better answers. But if it _does_ work, I'm very happy to keep it :)

Comment: I try to match by `name`, and it doesn't work (see e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/513707/awesome-window-manager-open-chromium-developer-tools-on-different-screen-than and http://superuser.com/questions/315770/awesome-window-manager-rule-assigning-programs-to-tags) :/